# How can I repair this concrete driveway

Tags: concrete, repair, driveway

I just noticed this spot on my driveway near an expansion joint, where the edge has fragmented (almost like something heavy was dropped.)  How could I repair it so that it is a straight edge again?
[image: photo of fragmented concrete edge]

Comment: Well yes, Cap'n Obvious.  :)  The point of my question was the 'straight edge' part.  I don't expect the color to perfectly match, but I'd like to end up with a comparable contour, edge, and texture.  And I would, naturally, be removing the loose parts at the outset, and filling with concrete along the way.

Comment: Is there an elevation discontinuity there? Or just the busted concrete? My instinct is that there's a significant differential settlement right there, but the concrete combined with a rebar dowel at that location could not hold things together. Last time I saw something like that, expansive soil was to blame.

Comment: No lippage, just busted.   I had not thought about expansive soil.  I feared that I had subpar concrete, and the weight of a car tire snapped it off.   I don't know if there is rebar at that location or not (I'll see when I clear out the chunks.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a simple repair. Remove all the loose, broken pieces. Get a large trowel and wedge it in between the concrete and the expansion joint. Get some concrete patch or epoxy patch. Some brands even have different colors. Fill in the area with the patching material. You can add a few Tapcons partially screwed in for reinforcing if needed. Then get a hand edger from your home store for a couple of bucks and round off the corner after removing the trowel.

Comment: I love the tapcon idea.  I'll be sure to do that.

Comment: I'm not sanguine about using a rigid patch there, unless you live in an area with a mild climate.  Something a little more flexible would be more durable.